# Material UI nested class override

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Im using muiSelect and there is a css selector that im trying to overwrite:

```
.MuiSelect-select.MuiSelect-select
```

How can I override this? Ive tried a couple things already like

```
MuiSelect: {
  select: {
    "& $MuiSelect-select":
  }
}
```

Which doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
MuiSelect: {
  select: {
    '&&': { ... },
  }
}
```

[This is the line of source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/NativeSelect/NativeSelect.js#L42) where the default is set (paddingRight: 24px), and the mui theme key to override it is `'&&'`. I was able to find this by first finding the source code of the native select component, and then searching for the css value that showed up on the dom element I was trying to override.